# Unable to use real device for react development

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to use my phone for react native. But I get a weird error and cannot seem to resolve it. Can anybody help? Here's the stack trace:

```
<everything fine above>

:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug

Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Aqua 4G+ - 5.0' for app:debug
Unable to install C:\Users\Mehul\Desktop\app\android\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all
        at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:89)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)
        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:137)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTas

<some more java errors>


02:58:27 E/427709463: Error while uploading app-debug.apk : Unknown failure ([CDS]close[0])
:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all
```

I've included just the necessary stack so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
I had to type:
adb kill-server

Wait a moment then run:

adb devices

In my case output is like are as follows

**List of Devices Attached**


*0123456789ABCDEF   device*

This will show you the DEVICE_ID (0123456789ABCDEF) of your device running android. 

then you will have to run below command and make sure usb is enabled 

react-native run-android --deviceId 0123456789ABCDEF

After that my output be like 


    **D:\React\albums>adb devices

    List of devices attached
    0123456789ABCDEF        device

    D:\React\albums>react-native run-android --deviceId 0123456789ABCDEF

    Scanning 636 folders for symlinks in D:\React\albums\node_modules (21ms)
    JS server already running.
    Building the app...
    Observed package id 'build-tools;23.0.1' in inconsistent location 'D:\Android\Sd
    k\build-tools\build-tools-23.0.1' (Expected 'D:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1')
    Already observed package id 'build-tools;23.0.1' in 'D:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\
    23.0.1'. Skipping duplicate at 'D:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\build-tools-23.0.1'
    Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location 'D:\An
    droid\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository.backup' (Expected 'D:\Android\Sdk\extras\go
    ogle\m2repository')
    Already observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in 'D:\Android\Sdk\extr
    as\google\m2repository'. Skipping duplicate at 'D:\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2r
    epository.backup'
    Observed package id 'system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86' in inconsistent l
    ocation 'D:\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86.backup' (Expect
    ed 'D:\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86')
    Already observed package id 'system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86' in 'D:\An
    droid\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86'. Skipping duplicate at 'D:\A
    ndroid\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86.backup'
    Observed package id 'build-tools;23.0.1' in inconsistent location 'D:\Android\Sd
    k\build-tools\build-tools-23.0.1' (Expected 'D:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.1')
    Already observed package id 'build-tools;23.0.1' in 'D:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\
    23.0.1'. Skipping duplicate at 'D:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\build-tools-23.0.1'
    Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location 'D:\An
    droid\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository.backup' (Expected 'D:\Android\Sdk\extras\go
    ogle\m2repository')
    Already observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in 'D:\Android\Sdk\extr
    as\google\m2repository'. Skipping duplicate at 'D:\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2r
    epository.backup'
    Observed package id 'system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86' in inconsistent l
    ocation 'D:\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86.backup' (Expect
    ed 'D:\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86')
    Already observed package id 'system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86' in 'D:\An
    droid\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86'. Skipping duplicate at 'D:\A
    ndroid\Sdk\system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86.backup'
    Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DA
    TE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0451Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
    :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:validateSigningDebug
    :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkReleaseManifest
    :app:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:lintVitalRelease
    :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :app:assembleRelease
    :app:assemble
    :app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
    :app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
    :app:assembleDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:testDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:incrementalReleaseUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies
    :app:compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:assembleReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:testReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:test UP-TO-DATE
    :app:check
    :app:build
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 16.717 secs
    Running D:\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF reverse tcp:8081 t
    cp:8081
    Installing the app on the device (cd android && adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF install
    app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk: 1...ed. 3.2 MB/s (8067631 bytes in 2.442s)
            pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
    Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
    Starting the app on 0123456789ABCDEF (D:\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 01234
    56789ABCDEF shell am start -n com.albums/com.albums.MainActivity)...
    Starting: Intent { cmp=com.albums/.MainActivity }

**



The important part was the --deviceId XYZ. Without this, the apk would never get uploaded to the phone.

**First Way**

*** If you are using Latest version of React then shake your real device and press reload (In my case react-native cli version is 2.0.1 And react-native version 0.45.1 ) Dont put any machine address and port in dev setting ok ***


**if first method does not works then follow second method**

**Second Way**

Then, the app launched with a red screen... i had to shake it, dev settings, adjust the "debug server host & port for device", putting my computer's IP address and port, like this:

192.168.0.15:8081

Lastly, i had to shake my phone again and select RELOAD...
```